# Build query string in javascript and merge params in one param

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

So the issue here is I want to be able to build a query string and nest different params in one of the params in Javascript. I am able to do this in php using http_build_query function. I tried doing it in javascript but params are getting splitted by &.
Here's my php code

```
$query string = [
            'action'      => 'index',
            'url'         => '/test/app/sell.php?'. http_build_query([
                'id'      => $id,
                'name'    => $name,
                'state'   => $currentState,
                'p'   => 1,
            ])
        ));
```

which returns

```
url: "/test/app/sell.php?id=10&name=john&state=CA&p=1"
```

Here's my js url but it seperates the params.

```
url = "url=/test/app/sell.php?"&id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&state=" + form_name + "&p=" + 1"
```

which returns:

```
id: 2,
name: "john",
state: "CA",
p: 1,
url: "/test/app/sell.php?"
```

How can i add all the params to the url param and it should return something like this `url: "/test/app/sell.php?id=10&name=john&state=CA&p=1"`

Comment: It is odd that a variable that is clearly a string is being returned as an object. Are you using some sort of package?

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```js
// Version 1 - preferable IMO 
buildQuery = ({action, url}) => `${action}?${Object.entries(url)
  .map(pair => pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('='))
  .join('&')}`;

let query = buildQuery({
  action: "/test/app/sell.php",
  url: {
    id: 2,
    name: "john",
    state: "CA",
    p: 1
  }
});

console.log(`URL: ${query}`);
```

The `$_GET` values in PHP will be assigned as an array `['id'=>1, 'name'=>'john', ...]`. The full URL will not be set in your `$_GET` superglobal. To check your full URL, I believe some combination of the below code is what you are looking for:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$actual_link = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
echo "$actual_link;
// Support for HTTP and HTTPS
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
echo "$actual_link;
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: That builds the url but when I use ParseQueryString build in function to extract the url, I don't get the full url. It still splits the querystring into different different objects. So anything with after the & is a diff object in the query string when I use the ParseQueryString function.

Comment: I will need some more information regarding your `ParseQueryString` function. Where are you `extracting` the URL?  Please take a look at the updates I've posted

Comment: I'm extracting the url in react using the ```ParseQueryString``` function. Then extracting the url from the ParseQueryString. so I'm doing something like this in react ```let  queryString = ParseQueryString(window.location.search);``` then parse out the url object from queryString